# Powershell | Replace mailNickname with variable

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

trying to replace mailNickname for all user with their own samaccountname:

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$SAM = (Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Staged,OU=corp,DC=mycompany,DC=com" -Filter * | select samaccountname)

foreach ($User in $SAM.samaccountname)
{
    Set-ADUser $User -Replace @{mailNickName = "$SAM"}
    }
```

This script sets mailNickName blank. Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix your problem with the least code change necessary, you should change your `$SAM` reference to `$User` in the `Set-ADUser` call.  You're currently setting mailNickName to the user object returned by `Get-ADUser` and not the sAMAccountName you're iterating over.

Your variable names are a bit confusing though because they're named somewhat opposite of what the names actually represent. In your code `$SAM` is actually a list of ADUser objects that have all of their properties filtered out except for samaccountname.  Your `$User` variable in the foreach loop is actually the samaccountname string from each user object.

Here's a minor variation of your code with changed variable names and the extraneous select statement removed.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Staged,OU=cor,DC=mycompany,DC=com" -Filter *
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Set-ADUser $user -Replace @{ mailNickName = "$($user.samaccountname)" }
}
```

Here's another variation that uses `ForEach-Object`'s `%` alias directly against the results of the `Get-ADUser` call.

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Staged,OU=cor,DC=mycompany,DC=com" -Filter * | %{
    Set-ADUser $_.DistinguishedName -Replace @{ mailNickName = $_.samaccountname }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple method to update the all users' mailNickName by the user's Samaccount Name via csv.

Prepare the csv file with header Samaccount and NickName and run script below. I used book4.csv on the root of my D drive as my csv.

```
Import-Csv "D:\Book4.csv" | % {Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Samaccount -Properties MailNickName | Set-ADUser -Replace @{MailNickName = "$($_.NickName)"}}
```